# Getting ADC value of potentiometer at a 100 ms sample rate. For the sample, would using a timer for a delay suffice?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, timer, pll

I am using the ADC on my HCS12 to get the value of a potentiometer. I am already using a PLL and a prescaler to change the frequency of the clock.

Due to the requirements on my board, this value must be within 2 MHz and 500 kHz. The thing is that I want to take different samples of the ADC every 100 ms.

Should I use the Free-Running Timer built into the board to get the period of my sample rate, or could I make a simple delay function?

Comment: Do you have a schematic or can you draw one with the tool (edit).

Comment: Using a delay function is almost never a good approach, if ever

Comment: @Linkyyy Why is that? Should I use a timer?

Comment: Do you want it to do anything else while waiting for the sample?

Comment: most applications would have a timer generate a timer tick of 1ms..10ms in order to manage timing and scheduling functions. So, yes, use a timer to provide a timing reference to fire the adc reading.